# How to add AD FS Server to authenticate against AD

Tags: azure, active-directory, adfs

I'm trying set up a Primary AD FS 3.0 Server in Windows Azure for Office 365 Single Sign-On.  I have no idea how to add a VM I provisioned to the local domain.

I've been following the directions here http://office365support.ca/setting-up-the-primary-ad-fs-3-0-server-in-windows-azure-for-office365-single-sign-on/ and can't proceed because I can't figure this out.  Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want to [Promote a Windows 2012R2 Server to Domain Controller](https://www.interworks.com/blog/ijahanshahi/2014/01/06/promoting-windows-2012r2-server-domain-controller) or [Install a new Active Directory forest on an Azure virtual network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-new-forest-virtual-machine/) but these two articles should cover everything.